# Can't install JDK on Windows 7, "Wrapper.CreateFile failed with error 123"

Tags: windows-7, installation, jdk

I'm trying to install JDK on Windows 7, 32 Bit. I'm logged in as administrator, but it tells me:

> Installer: Wrapper.CreateFile failed with error 123:
>   The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I tried the solutions from [this link too](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/installer-wrappercreatefile-failed-with-error-123/3b180316-95c2-4613-8c38-8515481db22c), following method one, but didn't try the others as the thread suggests they don't really help.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with JRE also. Filemon shows the following file creation failed with INVALID NAME:

`C:\Users\????????\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.7.0_02\Data1.cab`

I believe a bad account name causes `????????`. Try using an account with English letters only.

Answer (score 1):

I had a message like yours or another one ("download failed to ...`\LocalLow`") when I tried to execute directly from java website).

I checked out that folder (LocalLow), in fact there was a problem with that folder's ownership (the owner was "unknown" and I still don't know how was it possible) so I **changed the ownership of the folder as "user"** and I managed to install Java without any error message.

Answer (score 1):

On my Vista PC, the folder %HOMEPATH%/AppData/LocalLow was not writable neither for me nor for Administrators. Granting "write" permissions to this "LocalLow"-Folder solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't worked for me either, where Java can't be install on a computer that has illegal characters (non A-B, Characters, Numbers) within the user account's name, i.e. (C:\Users\ **AccountName**\ ...).

So create a new user account (A-B...) and re-install the Java run-time.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it is late but just now I had the same issue. I just created a new user in control panel and logged into new user and fixed!!!
win 7 32 bit
installing JDK